# Add FID to attribute table using ogrinfo

Tags: sql, ogr, sqlite, osgeo4w, ogrinfo

I want to add the fid to the attribute table using ogrinfo in OSGeo4W Shell.

Here is my code:

```
ogrinfo layer.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE layer ADD COLUMN ID integer" 
ogrinfo layer.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE layer SET ID = FID"
```

The GDAL:OGR SQL help https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html points out that sometimes it is necessary to add the fid as a column, as it is the case for me.

Does anyone has a clue how to solve this? Maybe by iterating a rownumber?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a simple way to add a rownumber with ogr

```
ogrinfo layer.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE layer set ID = rowid+1"
```

Comment: Why do you use `rowid+1`? I think `rowid` starts at 1 -> https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html#the_autoincrement_keyword

Comment: No, it starts with 0. For this reason I add +1. Kind regards.